# Mac Folder Icons

Tags: macos, icons, directory

I recently downloaded the Uber Press Kit (just for kicks) an noticed that the unzipped folder had some stylized icons (see below):

http://postimg.org/image/ab7vw58yn/
(Couldn't post actual image bc I don't have enough reputation points yet, ugh, but it's not spam.)

1. How did they do this?
2. How can I do this, and is it easy to do? (Would be helpful when organizing my documents if some of the folders are color-coded.)

Thanks !

EDIT: You can copy the icon, adjust the color in Preview or Photoshop, then easily paste in from the Get Info dialogue. Pretty cool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do this as outlined in this doc:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19073?locale=en_US